# Python 3 in Windows. Merge `curl.exe` or any .exe with existing Python code using PyInstaller to produce a single .exe

Tags: python-3.x, windows, curl

This is my simple Python script to check public IP. As you can see, `curl.exe` is required in this program. By default, there is no `curl` program in Windows OS.

```
import os

print("\n Checking ... ")
os.system('curl.exe icanhazip.com --proxy x.x.x.x')
os.system("pause")
```

**The exe with `curl` downloaded on Windows PC**

```
C:\>test_v1.exe

 Checking ...
y.y.y.y <== Public IP Address

C:\>
```

The problem started when I convert this code to exe and export it to another Windows computer without curl program in it.

**The exe without `curl` on Windows PC**

```
C:\>test_v1.exe

 Checking ...
'curl.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Press any key to continue . . .

C:\>
```

Would it be possible to merge `curl.exe` inside this code so that another user don't have to download curl in order to use this `test_v1.exe` program?

Comment: Perhaps, using [PycURL](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/install.html#ssl-certificate-bundle), you can do what you want.

Comment: According to the link ...

`Currently official PycURL packages are built against the following Python versions:

    2.7.10
    3.2.5
    3.3.5
    3.4.3
    3.5.2
    3.6.0
`

I'm using Python 3.7.0 and having a problem when `pip install pycurl`

Error is 

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 10 in C:\Users\user01\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-xjcpslax\pycurl\`

Comment: Please question the schedule to correspond to 3.7.x. [The curl-and-python mailing list](http://cool.haxx.se/mailman/listinfo/curl-and-python)

Comment: You could just use `requests`?